# How to interchange x and y axis when plotting using xarray?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am plotting some data from the cdasws.datarepresentation. I have plotted the plots using matlabplotlib but i cannot figure out how to flip the axes and i couldnt find it in the documentation.

here is the code

```py
%pip install xarray
%pip install cdflib
%pip install cdasws

from cdasws import CdasWs
from cdasws.datarepresentation import DataRepresentation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cdas = CdasWs()

datasets = cdas.get_datasets(observatoryGroup='Wind')

for index, dataset in enumerate(datasets):
    print(dataset['Id'], dataset['Label'])
    if index == 5:
        break

variables = cdas.get_variables('WI_H1_WAV')
for variable_1 in variables:
    print(variable_1['Name'], variable_1['LongDescription'])

data_1 = cdas.get_data('WI_H1_WAV', ['E_VOLTAGE_RAD1'],
                     '2020-07-11T02:00:00Z', '2020-07-11T03:00:00Z',
                     dataRepresentation = DataRepresentation.XARRAY)[1]
print(data_1)

### this is a bit of code to obtain the first part of the lower frequency data

print(data_1.E_VOLTAGE_RAD1)


data_1['E_VOLTAGE_RAD1'].plot()
```

The plot looks like this.

[image]

Is there a way to flip the axes?

I tried

```
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
```

but that didnt help

Comment: I think you missed a set of backticks and your formatting got all reversed. make sure to give your question a read over before posting! see the guide to [formatting](/help/formatting) for tips.

Answer (score 2):

when you plot a 2-dimensional array, the default plotting handler is [`xr.DataArray.plot.pcolormesh`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.plot.pcolormesh.html), so arguments will be handled by that function. To see the full set of available plotting methods and the default handler for 1, 2, and 3 dimensions, see [`xr.DataArray.plot`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.plot.html) and the [Plotting](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/plotting.html) section of the user guide.

The first two (optional) arguments to `DataArray.plot.pcolormesh` are the dims that get interpreted as the plot's `x` and `y` axes. From the API documentation:

> - **x** (`str`, *optional*) – Coordinate for x axis. If `None`, use `darray.dims[1]`.
> - **y** (`str`, *optional*) – Coordinate for y axis. If `None`, use `darray.dims[0]`.

So in your case, just provide the dimension names. I'm not sure what they're called in your data, but it should be something like this:

```py
data_1['E_VOLTAGE_RAD1'].plot(x='epoch', y='frequency')
```